# Dictionary autocomplete extension for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, google-chrome-extension

I tried googling for this but I didn't have any luck. Is there an autocomplete extension for chrome for spelling? Just like in Eclipse when I type

```
System.out.pri
```

then CTRL+SPACE it will bring up a menu with `print`, `println`, etc.

I want this as an extension for chrome, but instead of for programming words, just for english words. E.g. I type

```
isol
```

and then CTRL+SPACE and it will bring up a menu with words that start with "isol" (e.g. isolated).

So does this already exist or will I have to write it myself?

Comment: This question isn't about programming and is probably too localized. "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development"

Comment: If you question were "I'm writing an autocomplete app for Chrome but I'm running into a weird error..." then it would be on-topic for SO.  I'm afraid this question is not on-topic.

Comment: Sorry, I completely agree with you. I was just hoping that since so many people here use chrome (and extensions) that it might have just been community knowledge and I could get a quick answer. No hard feelings if you decide to close this question.

Comment: Your question is, in a fact, a great idea for an extension. Something dictionary-based would really help a lot of people.

Comment: Dude, did you write (or find) it?