# How can I access Chrome's spell-check dictionary?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, spell-checking

Clearly Chrome has a built-in dictionary that it uses for spell-checking. Is there an API or some way to access this dictionary? I am interested not in checking spelling, but actually accessing the dictionary. E.g. I would like to write [Dictionary autocomplete extension for chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993602/dictionary-autocomplete-extension-for-chrome) a dictionary autocomplete extension that uses Chrome's dictionary instead of maintaining my own. Of particular interest to me would be a funciton like `getWordsThatStartWith(text)`.

Comment: I doubt doing this would be simple. You'd probably have to use the NPAPI features to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The dictionaries are available for download from http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/. (Files with `.dic` extension.)

Comment: This URL seems to work better as of 11/2018: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/hunspell_dictionaries/

Comment: This URL works even better ;-) https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/hunspell_dictionaries/+/refs/heads/main

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is related to your request.  It appears another developer created an extension to look up words, not sure if the api he founded used the internal dictionary spell-check or not...my assumption would be that the api merely return results from a google query using an advance search feature like "define: example", example being the query/word. Here's a link to the article though it's quite outdated.

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html